# Azure Dashboard Refresh doesn't update the data

Tags: azure-monitor-workbooks, azure-dashboard

**The problem:**

I have some Azure workbook queries pinned to my Azure Dashboard. The problem I found is that manually refreshing the Dashboard or the Workbook queries doesn't give me the updated data. However, reloading the Dashboard web page does give me the updated data.

**What I have tried**:

Use a chrome extension to automatically reload the page at set intervals. This helps me create a self-updating dashboard. However, I was wondering if there's a solution to this that doesn't involve third party tools.

Answer (score 0):

Workbook parts pinned to azure dashboards will autorefresh with the azure dashboard's timerange and autorefresh settings if they are configured to use time range parameters:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/visualize/workbooks-overview#dashboard-time-ranges

[image: time range parameter usage]

without a time range parameter, the dashboard doesn't know how to *correctly* modify user queries to use the dashboard's time range.  (not all of the workbooks data sources support query text, so it isn't just parsing/modifying text)

for some data sources, like Azure Resource Graph, that itself have no built in concept of time, if you wanted the part to autorefresh, the simplest workaround is to add a comment in the query text that references the time range parameter.  the query won't actively use it, but the step then knows it depends on a time range parameter and will be autorefreshed.

Comment: Using the time range parameter still doesn't show me the updated data. "Updated data" here is referring to recent telemetry collect by the Analytics workspace.
For example, I let the dashboard stay still for 10 minutes. Within that 10 minutes, I sent some pageview telemetry to the workspace. Then I clicked refresh on the dashboard and on the query itself, and the resulting time axis gets updated but it displays 0 telemetries. In order to display those recent telemetries, i need to reload the web page.

Comment: in your pinned part, on your dashboard, in the subtitle of that part, it will say something like "[name of resource] (Last 10 minutes @ 4/21/22 10:52 am)", if it is using a time range parameter OR it will say "[name of resource] (@4/21/22 10:52am)" which will indicate when the query ran.  if you don't see a time range before the @ sign, this step isn't properly hooked up to a time range parameter and won't autorefresh, and if manually refreshed at the dashboard level, probably also gets served up from a local cache, because it isn't using a time range parameter, it must be static